# Покраснение (не уверен в том, что это ошибка) в XML ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, xml, android-xml

На момент написания XML кода у меня возникло недопонимание происходящего, мне необходимо выставить четкие ограничения, которые корректно работают только в Constraint, проблема в том, что у меня в коде таких лайоутов несколько и они по каким-то причинам выделяются красным цветом, ПРИ ЭТОМ, IDE (AS) не ругается на них, как это понимать, это ошибка или способов различия между лайоутами, мол вот желтый, вот красный - не перепутаешь(К этой теории могу добавить, что основной Лайоут вообще зелёный). НЕ могу понять..

UPD: Меня напрягает тот факт, что на разметке ХМЛ всё может быть нормально и показывать без ошибок, что, собственно, так оно и есть, однако на внешнем носителе/эмуляторе всё может быть иначе(Не запускал, до сих пор проблемы с этим, по каким-то причинам.)

Вот мой XML код. На ошибки не смотрите, я не выставлял ограничения, в процессе, просто не хочу сидеть и делать долгое время, чтобы оказалось, что это не будет работать.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="390dp"
    android:layout_height="844dp"
    android:background="@color/purplebg"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="ExtraText">


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/user_profil"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Usernane"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.048"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.523" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_profil"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView20"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="119dp"
            android:text="2,343"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.866"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/num1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView17"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="193dp"
            android:text="Posts"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/num1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="191dp"
            android:text="2,423"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/avatar"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView19"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="111dp"
            android:text="Followers"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView17"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="31dp"
            android:text="Following"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView19"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
            android:text="8,983"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.857"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView20"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="288dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profilepic2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/username_an"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="195dp"
        android:background="@color/Black5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_profil">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView27"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            android:text="Followed by username, username&#xA;and 100 others"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:text="Username"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView18"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:text="SubUserName"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            android:text="Discription"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
            android:text="Linktree"
            android:textColor="@color/WhiteText5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_compone"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:clipToOutline="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="325dp">

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_compone"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:clipToOutline="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="200dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="325dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image: Скриншот кода и то, как выглядит красное выделение]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нормально всё. Это просто значит, что вы выделили этот Layout.